# Can't Access My Service Methods

Tags: android

i'm at my wits end, following the examples on the android devguide to creating a bound service here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html

i created a bound service to play media files however, every time i try to access any of it's public methods from my activity, i get the force close error with a NullPointerException on logcat.

MediaService.java

```
public class MediaService extends Service {

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private SeekBar seeker;
private Boolean curRdy;
private Boolean paused;
private Cursor cursor;
private int columIndex;
private int position;

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {

    MediaService getService() {

        return MediaService.this;

    }

}

@Override

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

      return START_STICKY;

}

@Override

public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    curRdy = false;
    paused = false;

}

@Override

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return (IBinder) new LocalBinder();

}
```

PlayerTab.java

```
public class PlayerTab extends Activity {

private Intent intent;
private SeekBar seeker;
private MediaService serv;

private ServiceConnection servCon = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

        serv = ((MediaService.LocalBinder) service).getService();

    }

    @Override

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {

        //-----

    }

};

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);

    intent = new Intent(PlayerTab.this, MediaService.class);
    seeker = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seeker);

}

@Override

protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();
    startService(intent);
    bindService(intent, servCon, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    serv.loadPlayerSeeker(seeker);

}
```

serv.loadPlayerSeeker() is one of the public methods in MediaService, when ever i try to access it or any of the other methods, it just fails. the service will create and start just fine, it just doesn't seem bounded to the PayerTab activity properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `serv.loadPlayerSeeker(seeker);` until AFTER `public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {` is invoked.

Comment: so its not invoked at bindService(intent, servCon, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); ? thanks for the reply

Comment: `bindService` isn't blocking, so when you invoke that it returns immediately, even if the Service hasn't been started yet. The `onServiceConnected` method will be invoked at some other time, so until that is invoked you can not be certain that `serv` has been set.

Comment: ah i see, thanks for clearing that up. so i moved out `serv.loadPlayerSeeker()` out of the onStart method and put it into the play button's method. unfortunately that still didn't fix my issue. still get the NullPointException when the play button is clicked on the UI.

Comment: Then `onServiceConnected` is not being called. Can you verify that `onBind` is being called?

Comment: interesting, onBind is not being called. i put a toast message on it and sure enough, the message didn't show.

Comment: Is `onCreate` being called in the service at all?

Comment: Quite odd: try removing the AUTO_CREATE flag and putting the `bindService` call before the `startService` call.

Comment: putting `bindservice` before didn't help and `startservice` seem to actually require the flag because i got a syntax error without it. i'm reading up on `bindservice` and discovered that it returns false when it fails to bind a service. i put an if/else around my `bindservice` that will display a "true" msg on true and "false" on false. sure enough, it displays the "false" msg, still not sure why it fails though.

Comment: Ah, meant set the third arg to 0.

Comment: Ah, seems rudimentary, but I'll ask: do you have the `service` declaration in the AndroidManifest.xml for the MediaService class?

Comment: sure do, forgot to mention that on the original question.

Comment: Meh: forgot that `onCreate` wouldn't fire if you didn't have that.